# timeout exception error on using headless chrome webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

My selenium code is working without headless mode but when I try to do with headless mode , it raise TimeOutException error. I am using python selenium chrome webdriver. I am testing this on my local machine at address http://127.0.0.1:5000/
I am trying to log in Instagram with selenium but it's not working in headless mode. I tries to resize the window (maximizing, manually setting the size, resize_to) but none of them working.

```
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument("—disable-gpu")
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
chrome_driver = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_driver,chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver.set_window_size(1382, 744)
```

I am using this below helper function to wait for elements

```
def waiting(xpath):
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, xpath))
    )
    return element
```

My code to login in Instagram is below :

```
driver.get("https://www.instagram.com")
username = waiting("/html/body/div[1]/section/main/article/div[2]/div[1]/div/form/div/div[1]/div/label/input")
username.send_keys("abcdeff")
password = waiting("/html/body/div[1]/section/main/article/div[2]/div[1]/div/form/div/div[2]/div/label/input")
password.send_keys("password")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/section/main/article/div[2]/div[1]/div/form/div/div[3]/button").click()
```

I am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\madhav\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2070, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\madhav\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1515, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\madhav\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1513, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\madhav\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1499, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**req.view_args)
  File "C:\Users\madhav\Desktop\Fprojects\insta-sam\temp.py", line 47, in login
    username = waiting("/html/body/div[1]/section/main/article/div[2]/div[1]/div/form/div/div[1]/div/label/input")
  File "C:\Users\madhav\Desktop\Fprojects\insta-sam\temp.py", line 30, in waiting
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
  File "C:\Users\madhav\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

Comment: First of all do not use Absolute paths in your script it will tend to breakdown. Select tag either using **"id"** or you can write **"xpath"**. I have not checked but most probably your code is breaking because of absolute path.

Comment: I am passing the xpath of elements in waiting helper function, but still giving the error. I found that I couldn't find element by using tagname. Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have tried the below code and it is working for me. Please give it a try and if it solves your problem then please mark it as answer. Remember to change **yourUserName** and **YourPassword** in the code.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
options.add_argument(
    "user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
action = ActionChains(driver)

driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/")

wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, "username"))).send_keys("yourUserName")
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, "password"))).send_keys("YourPassword")
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[text()='Log In']/parent::button"))).click()

print(driver.current_url)
```

Note - Instagram is detecting that you are using selenium in headless mode. To avoid that you can use the fake useragent like `options.add_argument("user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36")`.

Hope it will resolve your problem. Thank you.!

Comment: Thank you so much it worked for me, Instagram was detecting the bot.

Comment: After clicking on login button, it throwed me error, so I took screenshot by using selenium and found that Instagram saying that "We detected an unusual login attemp, send security code", How can I ensure instagram that I am the real user which is just trying to log in with bot and to bypass the security check ? Thanks

Comment: nice, you save me a day, thanks!

Answer (score -2):

You are getting an error at step `username`. I generally don't prefer using "WebDriverWait()....until(.....)". I always use:

```
import time
...
...
time.sleep(10)
...
...
```

This always solves my problem, and is efficient as well!
As Swaroop has mentioned, you should avoid using the complete `xpath` as far as possible! The code may breakdown.

Comment: Still not working after using these waits. I think the page is white blank in headless mode, because not even a single element is attached to the page.